# MySQL, get the three clients who have the max purchases:

Tags: mysql, database

I have three mySQL tables :-

- client
- product
- purchase

**I wanna get the three clients who have the max purchases of the product with id = 1:**

```
client:-

client_id | name
1         | client1
2         | client2
3         | client3
4         | client4

product:-
    prod_id | name
    1         | product1
```

**purchase:**

```
purchase_id | client_id | product_id
1           | 1         |1
2           | 1         |1
3           | 1         |1
4           | 1         |1
5           | 2         |1
7           | 2         |1
8           | 2         |1
9           | 3         |1
10          | 3         |1
11          | 4         |1
```

=> I wanna get the following result:

-client1

-client2

-client3

How can I do?

Comment: `group by`, `count` and `limit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT client.name
FROM client
JOIN purchase ON purchase.client_id = client.client_id
JOIN product ON purchase.product_id = product.product_id and product.product_id = 1
GROUP BY client.client_id
ORDER BY COUNT(purchase.purchase_id) DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Comment: where is the table product ?

Comment: You don't need it if you are just counting the purchases.

Comment: Well.. I guess you can join products too if it makes you feel better :)